# create a custom sequential global dispatch queue

Tags: ios, objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

In many places in my app I use the next code to perform background tasks and notify the main thread:

```
dispatch_queue_t backgroundQueue = dispatch_queue_create("dispatch_queue_#1", 0);
    dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, ^{

   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{


        });
    });
```

Is it possible to create a backgroundQueue in one place (where does the best way?) and use it later?
I know about the system global queue, but ordering is important for me.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Something like this should work fine:

```
dispatch_queue_t backgroundQueue() {
    static dispatch_once_t queueCreationGuard;
    static dispatch_queue_t queue;
    dispatch_once(&queueCreationGuard, ^{
        queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.something.myapp.backgroundQueue", 0);
    });
    return queue;
}
```

Comment: could you please add an example of using it?

Comment: Sure: dispatch_async(backgroundQueue(), ^{ NSLog(@"Logged on the background queue!"});

Comment: I typed it directly into stack overflow, so perhaps I typoed something. It's an extremely simple C function, the compiler error should be clear and you can just fix it.

Comment: you are right (just a little unusual syntax for me); many thanks
 - http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091-CH102-SW6

Comment: If you include this method in your class implementation, you probably should precede the method declaration with a `-` if you want to make it an instance method or a `+` if you want to make it a class method. This code snippet is a C function, but adding a `-` or a `+` can make it part of your class implementation.

Comment: Since barn.gumbl requested a global queue, I'm assuming they specifically *don't* want it to be part of a class. Otherwise, yes, I would have made it a method.

Answer (score 1):

```
queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.something.myapp.backgroundQueue", 0);
```

Preceding is Serial Queue,if you want create concurrent queue,you can use DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT.

In iOS 5 and later, you can create concurrent dispatch queues yourself by specifying DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT as the queue type.

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("downLoadAGroupPhoto",
                                                   DISPATCH_QUEUE_CONCURRENT);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also us an NSOperationQueue and push operations to it.  To make sure the operations don't run out of order, you can set isConcurrent to NO.

Answer (score -7):

```
  dispatch_async( dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
                //back ground thread

                 dispatch_async( dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                     // main thread
                      });
                });
```